# Horizontally Laying out content with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app that uses Bootstrap. I have a column along the right side of the page (similar to the "asked", "viewed", "hot meta posts", "jobs" area on this question's page). In that column, I need to add some controls that will allow the user to enter a range of values. I want these controls to fill up the available space. They need to look something like this:

```
[textbox] - [textbox]
start       finish
```

In an attempt to create this, I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
    -
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input tpe="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This creates an ugly looking page. The reason its ugly is because the control doesn't fill the whole width (because only 11 of the 12 available columns are used). In addition, too much space is given to the column with the dash. For those reasons, I then tried the following:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><input type="text" class="form-control" /></li>
  <li>-</li>
  <li><input type="text" class="form-control" /></li>
</ul>
```

This approach took up the available width. However, my textboxes are stacked on top of each other now. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with CSS? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code i hope it will solve the issue,

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start">
  <div class="input-group-addon">-</div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Finish">
</div>
```

Comment: That's close! Except I cannot have the add-on styling around the '-'

Comment: Figured it out. Added the following to the - div: background-color:#fff; border: 0px solid #fff;

Comment: this code will solve the basic problem, and along with this you can add more CSS to get the exact look which will match your site design.